# UILocalNotification always give default sound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uilocalnotification

I want to add custom sound in interactive localnotification. I have write this code in appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    scheduleNotification()
}
    func scheduleNotification() {
    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    // Schedule the notification ********************************************
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications!.count == 0 {

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Hey! Update your counters ;)"
        // let URLToMyFile = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("notes_of_the_optimistic.caf")

        let ring: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("notes_of_the_optimistic", ofType: "caf")!
        print(ring)
        notification.soundName = ring
        notification.fireDate = NSDate()
        notification.category = categoryID
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

I have added notes_of_the_optimistic.caf file in my project but my nitification always give the default sound. The length of the sound file is 29sec. Can any budy tell me what I am missing.

Comment: You don't need get a full path of your custom sound, you need only sound name with file format like `notification.soundName = "notes_of_the_optimistic.caf"`

Comment: It's working , Thank You

Comment: @iSashok Please add as an answer so Avinash can Accept it. Other users will also be helped in future if you guys do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks I added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need get a full path of your custom sound, you need only sound name with file format `like notification.soundName = "notes_of_the_optimistic.caf"`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are sending in the entire path to your sound asset.

Replace

```
let ring: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("notes_of_the_optimistic", ofType: "caf")!
```

with

```
let ring: String = "notes_of_the_optimistic"
```

Answer (score -1):

> .caf and any manually type converted file will not work. use mp3 and
>   aiff (apple define format).

Comment: Where is this being quoted from?